# Core Plot with swift getting error : "Missing Argument for Parameter ‘frame’ in call"

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

I am trying to use core plot with swift and I feel very close except for one error. My code so far is :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CPTPlotDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var graphView: CPTGraphHostingView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // create graph
        var graph = CPTXYGraph(frame: CGRectZero)
        graph.title = "Hello Graph"
        graph.paddingLeft = 0
        graph.paddingTop = 0
        graph.paddingRight = 0
        graph.paddingBottom = 0
        // hide the axes
        var axes = graph.axisSet as CPTXYAxisSet
        var lineStyle = CPTMutableLineStyle()
        lineStyle.lineWidth = 0
        axes.xAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle
        axes.yAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle

        // add a pie plot
        var pie = CPTPieChart()
        pie.dataSource = self
        pie.pieRadius = (self.view.frame.size.width * 0.9)/2
        graph.addPlot(pie)

        self.graphView.hostedGraph = graph
    }

    func numberOfRecordsForPlot(plot: CPTPlot!) -> UInt {
        return 4
    }

    func numberForPlot(plot: CPTPlot!, field fieldEnum: UInt, recordIndex idx: UInt) -> NSNumber! {
        return idx+1
    }



}
```

The error i am getting is from the line : `var pie = CPTPieChart()` My error is :

> Core Plot with swift getting error : "Missing Argument for Parameter ‘frame’ in call"

I am following a tutorial and it is possible that swift has changed, however I am new to the language and can't seem to solve this one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you need to add a CGRect as a frame parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced similar problems while developing another app. To my experience, CGRectZero is causing problems with Swift. Try with an actual CGRect or call

```
var pie = CPTPieChart(frame: CGRectMake(x,y,width,height))
```